# One point compatification is unique up to homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology

In the proof of this theorem below I don't understand two thing first is why is the set U is also open in $\tilde{Y}$ when they mention "because X is open in $\tilde{Y}$, the set U is also open in $\tilde{Y}$ as desired.

This is in the first part of the proof, which shows uniqueness, i.e when U does not contain p.

In the second part when U contain p I don't understand why is $H(U) = \tilde{Y} - C$ I understand the rest.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part, you have a set $U\subseteq X$ that is open in $X$. $X$ is a subset of $Y'$, so there is some open set $V\subseteq Y'$ such that $U=X\cap V$. But $X$ is open in $Y'$, and the intersection of two open sets in $Y'$ is an open set in $Y'$, so $U$ is open in $Y'$.

For the second part, you have an open nbhd $U$ of $p$ in the space $Y$, and $C=Y\setminus U$. This means that $U=Y\setminus C$, so $h[U]=h[Y\setminus C]$, and since $h$ is a bijection, we actually have

$$h[U]=h[Y\setminus C]=h[Y]\setminus h[C]=Y'\setminus C\;.$$

(In case it’s not clear, $h[C]=C$ because $C\subseteq X$.)